# how to implement facebook feed using ionic framework for hybrid app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am working on a hybrid mobile app using ionic and cordova, In the app I am sharing pictures with comments in social media. I want to impliment "facebook feed" method to share pictures in facebook with custom comments.

I have tried [ngCordova's Facebook plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/facebook) but I faced some Issues in that, where the issue ticket is still open in the plugin builder's github. So I removed this plugin.

I have seen [ngOpenFB](https://github.com/r-wettstaedt/ngOpenFB) but there I have'nt found $openFB.ui() method for feed dialog.

I want to know that is there any plugin available by which I can impliment Facebook feed for image sharing in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look for your facebook integration in your hybrid app [nicraboy](https://blog.nraboy.com/2015/02/make-facebook-mobile-app-ionic-framework/)

Comment: Thanks @Anil kumar.The tutorial you have mentioned is really good but he have used get API to get all the feed. Yes I can post on the Users wall using $post, but this will not give the feed dialog to the user and it needs permissions from facebook also. So I cant use this solution. Thanks once again.

Comment: you want to share your image via social network's only na

Answer (score 1):

```
// Add to openfb.js and use it.
function ui(method,obj) {
        var method = method || 'GET',
            params = obj || {},
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            url;
        params['access_token'] = tokenStore.fbAccessToken;
        params['redirect_uri'] = 'http://localhost:8100/#/tab/chats';
        params['display'] = 'popup';
        params['sdk'] = 'joey';
        params['app_id'] = 'APP Id in Integer';
        url = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/' + method + '?' + toQueryString(params);
        window.open(url, '_open', 'location=no,clearcache=no');
        //window.open(url, '_self', 'location=no,clearcache=no');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also have a look at this repo: https://github.com/srameshr/ionic-starter-oauth

Comment: Thanks @InfinitePrime for your concern. Your article really helped me but My problem is quite different.